# 45° Slopes in a Tile based 2D platformer

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, platformer

I want to have simple 45° slopes in my tile based platformer, however I just cant seem to get the algorithm down. Please take a look at the code and video, maybe I'm missing the obvious?

```
//collisionRectangle is the collision rectangle of the player with 
//origin at the top left and width and height
//wantedPosition is the new position the player will be set to.
//this is determined elsewhere by checking the bottom center point of the players rect
if(_leftSlope || _rightSlope)
{        
    //Test bottom center point
    var calculationPoint = new Vector2(collisionRectangle.Center.X, collisionRectangle.Bottom);
    //Get the collision rectangle of the tile, origin is top-left
    Rectangle cellRect =
        _tileMap.CellWorldRectangle(
            _tileMap.GetCellByPixel(calculationPoint));
    //Calculate the new Y coordinate depending on if its a left or right slope
    //CellSize = 8
    float newY = _leftSlope
                            ? (calculationPoint.X % CellSize) + cellRect.Y
                            : (-1 * (calculationPoint.X % CellSize) - CellSize) + cellRect.Y;
    //reset variables so we dont jump in here next frame
    _leftSlope = false;
    _rightSlope = false;
    //now change the players Y according to the difference of our calculation
    wantedPosition.Y += newY - calculationPoint.Y;
}
```

Video of what it looks like:
http://youtu.be/EKOWgD2muoc

Comment: Aren't Vectors awesome? :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I understand reading your question, you want to calculate the correct `Y` position, given a `X` position of the player. This is rather trivial. Have a look at this image:

[image: slope]

Assuming your slope-tile is at a given position `x,y` (origin is bottom left as in the image). You have the player position `x1` and the width and the height of the sloped tile (`u, v`). `x, y` and `x1` are world coordinates.

Given these parameters, your players Y-position (`y1`) would be:

```
y1 = y + (x1 - x) * (v / u)
```

If you're only dealing with 45 degree angles, then it gets even simpler:

```
y1 = y + (x1 - x)
```

If the slope is the other way round, it's:

```
y1 = y + (v - (x1 - x))
```

Comment: after applying @SkimFlux fix plus your new formular plus some stupid things I overlooked it worked. thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you use y=mx+b for a simpler calculation?

Comment: @ashes999 I don't think it gets much simpler than what I wrote. What are `m` and `b` in your calculation?

Comment: @bummzack m is your slope (1 for a 45-degree slope downward, -1 for upward) and b would be the intercept on the x-axis. Grade 9 algebra. Just sayin'.

Comment: @ashes999 Yeah it has been a long time. Feel free to post this equation as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Although this is already answered, allow me to offer another equation: `y = mx + b`, where y is the coordinate calculated, m is the slope (-1 for down at 45 degrees, 1 for up at 45 degrees), and b is the y-intercept -- the y-coordinate where x=0.

This allows you slightly more flexibility; you can change m to calculate a different slope other than 45-degrees. For example, an m of pi/3 gives you a slope of 30 degrees.

Answer (score 4):

You may find a lot of value in this site:
http://info.sonicretro.org/Sonic_Physics_Guide

Specifically for what you are looking for check out the Solid Tiles: Slopes and Curves section. It basically shows you how it is believed this was accomplished in the early Sonic games.

Comment: interesting read, but too complex. This kind of slope is the only one I want, thus should simplify the solution. A height map/sensor/scanner system would be overkill for this. Thanks for digging up the link, though.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the Seperate Axis Theorm, It will solve your slope issue, but it does require quite a bit of maths and the theory itself takes a while to get your head round. I've linked you to a tutorial and a book which explains it  better

[metanetsoftware Tutorial](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html)

[Real-Time-Collision-Detection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558607323)

Comment: thats too much, imo. This is a highly simplified case and there'd be no need for other uses of SAT. Thanks for taking the time to pull up the links, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you either have an off-by-one error somewhere else, or you aren't setting _leftSlope/_rightSlope flags at the right time. This code does not touch the X movement at all, but that seems to be your problem in the video.

You should check if those flags are triggered at all. Then check your horizontal collision detection: you don't want it to trigger on a slope.

Comment: oh god right. I actually dont want either horizontal or vertical collision detection when this happens. I totally forgot to disable that. Looks somehow better now, but not done yet. Thanks.